# ReactJS: Cannot Read Property 'map' of Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component that fetches data and stores it into useState which then gets passed into a child component as a prop.

When that child component gets rendered, I store that prop data into useState which I try and then iterate over with a map or forEach function but I get `cannot read property of undefined errors`

when checking React Dev tools, the array that gets passed from Parent to child exists so im not too sure what im doing wrong.

Parent Component:

```js
const DisplayOpenIncidents = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const incidents = FetchIncidents();

    incidents.then((incidents) => {
      setData(incidents);
      setLoading(false);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <AccordionExample data={data} />
  );
};
```

Child Component:

```js
const AccordionExample = (props) => {
  const [test, setTest] = useState(props.data);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props.data); // Displays array
    setTest(props.data);
  }, [props]);

  return (
    <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
      <Card>
        <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey="0">
          TITLE
        </Accordion.Toggle>
        <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
          <Card.Body>
            {test.forEach((test) => {
              console.log(test);
            })}
          </Card.Body>
        </Accordion.Collapse>
      </Card>
    </Accordion>
  );
};
```

TIA

Comment: Why are you setting `test` inside a useEffect?

Comment: @evolutionxbox either way, setting it inside a useEffect or not at all still doesn't allow me to iterate over it

Comment: why are you copying props into state? this is a known [anti-pattern](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#anti-pattern-unconditionally-copying-props-to-state)

Comment: It is probably because - FetchIncidents is returning undefined. Is this supposed to be an asynchronous call? ie as const incidents =await  FetchIncidents();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the condition as follows

```
<Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
      <Card.Body>
        {test && test.forEach((test) => {
          console.log(test);
        })}
      </Card.Body>
    </Accordion.Collapse>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to recreate this with some numbers as incidents. The issues I see are...

1. Your `DisplayOpenIncidents` component doesn't have a return statement, so the `AccordionExample` component isn't being rendered.
2. Your `forEach` function doesn't return anything, so the component won't render. Running `map` will fix this.
3. You're passing a state from a parent to a child, then setting the state in the child. You don't need to do this.

Here's the code working with a substitute error array...

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"

const AccordionExample = (props) => {

  return (
    <div defaultActiveKey="0">
      <div>
        <div eventKey="0">
          TITLE
        </div>
        <div eventKey="0">
          <div>
            {props.data.map((test) => <p>{test}</p>)}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const incidents = [1, 2, 3]

  //incidents.then((incidents) => {
    setData(incidents);
    //setLoading(false);
  //});
}, []);

return (<AccordionExample data={data} />);
}


export default App
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, appreciate your detailed response here. I have taken your consideration about the props and state and have removed that from my child component. The solution in my cause was to involve another check before trying the .map/forEach loop. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have to put check when using **test** object like bellow

```
<Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
      <Card.Body>
        {test ? test.forEach((test) => {
          console.log(test);
        }) : "Error"}
      </Card.Body>
</Accordion.Collapse>
```